# Is there a convenient way to convert comma separated string to hashmap

Tags: java

String format is (not json format)：

```
a="0PN5J17HBGZHT7JJ3X82", b="frJIUN8DYpKDtOLCwo/yzg="
```

I want convert this string to a HashMap:

key `a` with value `0PN5J17HBGZHT7JJ3X82`

key `b` with value `frJIUN8DYpKDtOLCwo/yzg=`

Is there a convenient way? Thanks

What I've tried:

```
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    String s = "a=\"00PN5J17HBGZHT7JJ3X82\",b=\"frJIUN8DYpKDtOLCwo/yzg=\"";
    String []tmp = StringUtils.split(s,',');
    for (String v : tmp) {
        String[] t = StringUtils.split(v,'=');
        map.put(t[0], t[1]);
    }
```

I get this result:

key `a` with value `"0PN5J17HBGZHT7JJ3X82"`

key `b` with value `"frJIUN8DYpKDtOLCwo/yzg`

for key `a`, the start and end double quotation marks(") is unwanted; for key `b`, the start double quotation marks(") is unwanted and the last equals sign(=) is missing.
Sorry for my poor english.

Comment: @AlexErofeev yes, key are String

Comment: your input is like `String str = "0PN5J17HBGZHT7JJ3X82,frJIUN8DYpKDtOLCwo/yzg";` or `String str = "a=\"0PN5J17HBGZHT7JJ3X82\", b=\"frJIUN8DYpKDtOLCwo/yzg=\""` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Probably you don't care that it's a HashMap, just a Map, so this will do it, since Properties implements Map:

```
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.util.*;

public class Strings {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String input = "a=\"0PN5J17HBGZHT7JJ3X82\", b=\"frJIUN8DYpKDtOLCwo/yzg=\"";
        String propertiesFormat = input.replaceAll(",", "\n");
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.load(new StringReader(propertiesFormat));
        System.out.println(properties);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
{b="frJIUN8DYpKDtOLCwo/yzg=", a="0PN5J17HBGZHT7JJ3X82"}
```

If you absolutely need a HashMap, you can construct one with the Properties object as input: `new HashMap(properties)`.

Comment: Sorry for my unclear question. I don't want the quotation marks " in the value.I want result:{b=frJIUN8DYpKDtOLCwo/yzg=, a=0PN5J17HBGZHT7JJ3X82}

Answer (score 2):

Added few changes in Ryan's code

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String input = "a=\"0PN5J17HBGZHT7JJ3X82\", b=\"frJIUN8DYpKDtOLCwo/yzg=\"";
        input=input.replaceAll("\"", "");
        String propertiesFormat = input.replaceAll(",", "\n");
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.load(new StringReader(propertiesFormat));
        Set<Entry<Object, Object>> entrySet = properties.entrySet();
        HashMap<String,String > map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        for (Iterator<Entry<Object, Object>> it = entrySet.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
            Entry<Object,Object> entry = it.next();
            map.put((String)entry.getKey(), (String)entry.getValue());
        }
        System.out.println(map);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Split the String on the Basis of `commas (",")` and then with with `("=")`

```
String s = "Comma Separated String";
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

String[] arr = s.split(",");

String[] arStr = arr.split("=");

map.put(arr[0], arr[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the regex as below.

```
Map<String,String> data = new HashMap<String,String>();
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[\\{\\}\\=\\, ]++");
String[] split = p.split(text);
for ( int i=0; i+2 <= split.length; i+=2 ){
    data.put( split[i], split[i+1] );
}
return data;
```

Comment: You should take out the relevant Regex from that link and include it in your answer. That way, if the link ever rots, the answer is preserved.